# CallKit Block Number through JSON API

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I want to block incoming numbers to user through my JSON Api. I will get number lists in JSON API and I will use my NSURLSession api request in Call Directory Extension. Is it possible to achieve this? 
I was reading this article - https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios and they are adding one number as blacklist when extension will execute. 
As per apple docs extension will execute when System will receive any incoming calls. So Can we get enough time to fire api and block certain numbers? OR Can we use App groups to share database in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically Yes, We can fire a `URLSession` request from our app extensions. From Apple documentation

> An app extension can initiate uploads or downloads using an
>   NSURLSession object, with results of those operations, reported to the
>   containing app.

However, there is a high chance that it will not work as the background task might run for longer period of time. In your case triggering request and getting the JSON. Again from apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6) under the title "**Some APIs are unavailable to App extensions**"

> Perform long-running background tasks The specifics of this limitation
>   vary by platform, as described in the extension point chapters in this
>   document.

So the best way to achieve call blocking in your case is to download and store the list of phone numbers from containing app and share it with your call directory extension.

To make a note here, your phone numbers list should be sorted list of Int64's else you might end up with errors.

---

More info on [**Blocking Incoming Calls**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit)

You can use `addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber:)` method in the implementation of `override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext)` method.

```
class CustomCallDirectoryProvider: CXCallDirectoryProvider {
    override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
        let blockedPhoneNumbers: [CXCallDirectoryPhoneNumber] = [ … ]
        for phoneNumber in blockedPhoneNumbers.sorted(by: <) {
            context.addBlockingEntry(withNextSequentialPhoneNumber: phoneNumber)
        }

        context.completeRequest()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[The document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit) says :

> Because this method is called only when the system launches the app extension and not for each individual call, you must specify call identification information all at once; you cannot, for example, make a request to a web service to find information about an incoming call.

I think it has told you the answer.

Comment: This answer is correct, the Callkit ID/Blocking extension is not called for each incoming call, all numbers are registered when the extension loads.